# Prove that $M$ is finitely generated and semisimple, if Artinian and the intersection of all maximal submodules is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, artinian, semi-simple-rings

> Let $M$ be a $R$-module. It is given that intersection of all maximal submodules of $M$ is the zero module. Moreover, the module is given to be Artinian.
>
> Prove that $M$ is finitely generated and it is a semisimple module.

I feel I should somehow try to construct a non-empty collection of submodules of $M$ and then use the Artinian condition. But I could not construct such a collection.

Any help.

Comment: A minor comment: writing `$R-$ module` means "$R$ minus module", whereas `$R$-module` means $R$-module. (Putting the character `-` inside  MathJax makes it a minus sign.)

Comment: Do you know of radical and Artin-Wedderburn theorem?

Comment: YES  what to do next @Orat

Comment: Sorry, I had a misconception about finitely generated part (So forget about AW theorem). Semi simple part should be proven from the fact that radical is zero. May I ask your definition of semi simple module?

Comment: which can be written as direct sum of simple modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of maximal submodules of $M$.

**Lemma**: There exist a *finite* subset $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\bigcap \mathcal{N} = 0$.

**Proof**: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of the intersection finite number of maximal submodules. As $M$ is artinian, $\mathcal{C}$ must have a minimal element $N = \bigcap \mathcal{N}$. If it is not zero then there is a nonzero element $x \in N$ and a maximal submodule $M'$ of $M$ not containing $x$ (from the hypothesis $\bigcap \mathcal{M} = 0$). Then $M' \cap \bigcap \mathcal{N} < \bigcap \mathcal{N}$, which contradicts to the minimality of $\bigcap\mathcal{N}$.

Now for a proof of your question.

**Proof**: From the above lemma, the kernel of map $M \to \bigoplus_{N \in \mathcal{N}} M/N$ is $\bigcap \mathcal{N} = 0$. So it is semisimple (as $M$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $\bigoplus M/N$) and finitely generated (as $M/N$ is simple and hence $M/N = R\bar{x}$ for some $\bar{x} \in M/N$).

Comment: How do you know the collection $C$ is non-empty

Comment: If $M$ has a maximal submodule $U$ then $U$ is an element of $\mathcal{C}$. If not then it means $M = 0$ and it is obviously semisimple and finitely generated.

Comment: @Orat,, If $M$ has a maximal submodule $U$, then the collection is non-empty otherwise either $M=0$ or $M$ is simple and hence semisimple and finitely generated.

Answer (score 1):

From the artinian hypothesis you may deduce that the zero submodule is an intersection of finitely many maximal submodules. Therefore $M$ is isomorphic to a submodule of a finitely generated semisimple module, hence it is semisimple and finitely generated.